# ¿Como funciona el click count en java?

Tags: java

Ocupo ayuda sobre como funciona el click count en java, si me pudieran mostrar algunos ejemplos de su utilizacion me ayudaria bastante

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 2):

Este es un ejemplo sencillo:

```
int clicked = 0; // declaras una variable 
private void jButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{                                         
    // int clicked = 0; 
    clicked++; //cada que se ejecuta el evento sumará 1
    System.out.println(clicked); //Se imprime el valor
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta pero esperamos que las preguntas de este tipo tengan [mcve]

Comment: Enterado, y tienes razón al respecto ya que se nota la falta de esfuerzo por buscar una solución, espero de igual forma sea de ayuda para los demás.